# How to query from database when I have different foreign keys?

Tags: laravel, querying

I am trying to query data from my database and pass the results to a view called `events`, the problem I have is that one of my queries will always return the same result because in the `where` condition the `$events_id` is the same always. Is there a better way to do the querying? A better logic?

This code is from my controller called `EventController`:

```
public function index()
{
    $firm_id = DB::table('firms')->where('user_id', auth()->id())->value('id');
    $events_id = DB::table('events')->where('firm_id', $firm_id)->value('id');
    $events = DB::table('events')->where('firm_id', $firm_id)->get()->toArray();
    $actual_events = DB::table('actual_events')->where('event_id', $events_id)->get()->toArray();
    return view('events',['events' => $events,'actual_events' => $actual_events]);
}
```

Since the `$events_id` is the same every time, the `$actual_events` will only contain the first result.

The image I have uploaded shows the problem, my table's first three columns are fine. Starting from the fourth they contain repeated values:

[image: Problem illustration]

Comment: these tables have relation together or not ?

Comment: Yes actual event is related to event through event_id,while event is related to firm through firm_id if that is what you have asked.

Comment: why dont use `eloquent` is best for do it

Comment: I have tried using eloquent,but it did not work the way I tried,I am sure I have made a mistake there as well,but could not figure it out.

Comment: your query is very easy if you make on `eloquent`

Comment: Could you give me an example,here one actual event belongs to an event ,so this would be a one to one relation or one to many because in the future the same event may take place just in a different time?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve Explain Briefly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I guess, you need something like this:

> $event_ids = DB::table('events')->where('firm_id', $firm_id)->pluck('id');
>
> $actual_events = DB::table('actual_events')->whereIn('event_id', $event_ids)->get()->toArray();

or write about your problem in details and I will try to help you.

Answer (score 0):

you just said that your tables have relation together.
in this case it's better you using the eloquent for that,
first you should type the relations in model of each table like this:

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
    public function cities()
    {
        return $this->hasmany('App\City'); //you should type your relation
    }
}
```

for relations you can use this link: [laravel relationships](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships#defining-relationships)

after that when you compact the `$user` variable to your view, you can use this syntax for getting the city value relation to this user: `$user->cities;`.

Comment: Thank you for your patience and answer, I will try it out as soon as I am able.